# Using Autofilter in Function in vba

Tags: excel, vba

The below function is throwing error `424 Object Required` .

I want to use this in Worksheets asformula.

Data is available in Uploaded Report tab. Row 7 is the Header row .

```
Function Bookings(Start_date As Date, End_date As Date) As Long
    On Error GoTo Protection
    Dim l_row As Long
    Dim rngRow, resultRng, filterRng As Range
    Bookings = 0
    l_row = Worksheets("Uploaded Report").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    Worksheets("Uploaded Report").AutoFilterMode = False

    Set filterRng = Worksheets("Uploaded Report").Range("A7:E" & l_row)
    filterRng.AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:="GC Hi Top", VisibleDropDown:=True
    'Worksheets("Uploaded Report").Range("A7:E" & l_row).AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:=">=" & Format(Start_date, "mm/dd/yyyy"), Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="<=" & Format(End_date, "mm/dd/yyyy")
    Worksheets("Uploaded Report").Activate
    Set resultRng = filterRng.AutoFilter.Range.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

    For Each rngRow In resultRng
        If rngRow.Row = 7 Then
           GoTo NextIteration
        End If
        If Len(Worksheets("Uploaded Report").Range("A" & rngRow.Row).Value) > 0 Then
            If rngRow.Row > 1 And rngRow.Column = 3 Then
                Bookings = Bookings + 1
            End If
        End If
```

NextIteration:
        Next rngRow

Protection:
        MsgBox Err.Number & Err.Description

```
End Function
```

Comment: On which line the error occurs? To find out, you can comment out the `On Error GoTo Protection` line.

Answer (score 0):

### How to get rid of the error

When testing your code, the error was raised by the line:
`Set resultRng = filterRng.AutoFilter.Range.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)`

Change that line to :
`Set resultRng = filterRng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)`

---

### Other things

1. You have incorrectly declared variables i presume.

   `Dim rngRow, resultRng, filterRng As Range`
   change to
   `Dim rngRow As Range, resultRng As Range, filterRng As Range`
2. In the line for `l_row`, you are missing a parent for `Rows.count`
   `l_row = Worksheets("Uploaded Report").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row`
   change to
   `l_row = Worksheets("Uploaded Report").Cells(Worksheets("Uploaded Report").Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row`
   or use `With...End With` statement.
3. Are you sure you want Error handler in function? Without it it will just display excel error in the cell, without the MsgBox, which for clueless users is useless and scary. If you opt to keep the Error handler, add a line `Exit Function` **before** the `Protection:` label.
4. To be more efficient and to get rid of the redundant `If...End If` statements you can set the resultRng to
   `Set resultRng = filterRng.Columns(3).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)`
   This way you will only loop through column "C".